# if выражение, сравнивающее строки в java android [duplicate]

Tags: java, android, строки

Я пытаюсь написать программу, при работе которой будет выводиться изображение по нажатию кнопки. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при последующем открытии приложения это изображение было уже выведено(Пытаюсь это реализовать через сохранение файла на телефон при нажатии кнопки, а при последующем открытии приложения этот файл доставался и проверялся и, если значение файла=head_1=num(head_1 присваивается по нажатию кнопки), фотография выводиться

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String head, head_treatment;
private TextView text;
private Button by, sell;
private ImageView imgV;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();
    imgV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    imgV.setImageResource(R.drawable.startw);

    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);


    sell.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    treatment();
    read();

}

 private void addListenerOnButton(){
    by = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    by.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   imgV.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                   by.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   sell.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   head="head_1";
                   write();
                }
            }
    );

    sell = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    sell.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    imgV.setImageResource(R.drawable.startw);
                    by.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sell.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    head="head_0";
                    write();
                }
            }
    );


}

public void read(){
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInput = openFileInput("head.txt");
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileInput);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
        StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String lines;
        while ((lines=buffer.readLine()) != null){
            strBuffer.append(lines);
        }
        head_treatment=strBuffer.toString();
        text.setText(head_treatment);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void write(){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = openFileOutput("head.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutput.write(head.getBytes());
        fileOutput.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void treatment(){
    String nume = head_treatment;
    String num = "head_1";
    if (num.equals(nume)) {
        imgV.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
    } else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: используйте `SharedPreferences` для сохранения значения. Заголовок каким образом выбирался для вопроса?

Comment: "используйте SharedPreferences для сохранения значения. Заголовок каким образом выбирался для вопроса?"  Спасибо. Про какой именно заголовок идет речь?

Comment: Моя основная проблема заключается в том, что при сравнивании двух переменный в if приложение выдает ошибку и не запускается.

Comment: ну заголовок, то что выше текста. "if выражение, сравнивающее строки в java android [duplicate]" - как это связано с проблемой в вопросе, какой if, какие строки? и особенно что должно донести о проблеме [duplicate]

Comment: если у вас проблема в том, что что то не запускается при сравнении, то зачем вы пишите в вопросе и приводите код совсем другого. Здесь так мало экстрасенсов, что ваша "основная" проблема останется не решенной с таким оформлением вопроса. Переоформите все ( "править" под вопросом) опишите проблему, код связаный с ней и стектрейс при остановке приложения.